# Filter keys from map if it contains substring Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a map type Map[String,String] when i need to filter few keys when it does not have keyword `Some`. When key does not contain `Some`, i need to remove those key from Map.

For example:

```
   scala>     for ((k,v) <- map) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")
```

> key: List(DoubleMetric(Column,Completeness,Some((first IS NOT
> NULL)))), value: 0.6666666666666666 does not meet the constraint
> requirement
>
> key: List(DoubleMetric(Column,Uniqueness,Some(CASE WHEN (count() OVER
> (PARTITION BY first unspecifiedframe$()) = 1) THEN true ELSE false
> END))), value: None key:
> List(DoubleMetric(Column,Minimum,Some(CAST(year AS DOUBLE)))), value:
> None
>
> key:
> List(DoubleMetric(Column,Compliance,,Some(CAST((COALESCE(CAST(year AS
> DECIMAL(20,10)), 0.0) >= 0) AS INT)))), value: None key:
> List(DoubleMetric(Column,Maximum,Some(CAST(year AS DOUBLE)))), value:
> 1991.0 does not meet the constraint requirement!
>
> key: List(DoubleMetric(Column,Compliance,Some(CAST(((id IS NULL) OR
> (id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))) AS INT)))), value: 0.6666666666666666 does
> not meet the constraint requirement!
>
> key: List(DoubleMetric(Dataset,Size,*,Success(3.0),None)), value: 3
> does not meet the constraint requirement!

Expected result:

> key: List(DoubleMetric(Column,Completeness,Some((first IS NOT
> NULL)))), value: 0.6666666666666666 does not meet the constraint
> requirement
>
> key: List(DoubleMetric(Column,Uniqueness,Some(CASE WHEN (count() OVER
> (PARTITION BY first unspecifiedframe$()) = 1) THEN true ELSE false
> END))), value: None key:
> List(DoubleMetric(Column,Minimum,Some(CAST(year AS DOUBLE)))), value:
> None
>
> key:
> List(DoubleMetric(Column,Compliance,,Some(CAST((COALESCE(CAST(year AS
> DECIMAL(20,10)), 0.0) >= 0) AS INT)))), value: None key:
> List(DoubleMetric(Column,Maximum,Some(CAST(year AS DOUBLE)))), value:
> 1991.0 does not meet the constraint requirement!
>
> key: List(DoubleMetric(Column,Compliance,Some(CAST(((id IS NULL) OR
> (id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))) AS INT)))), value: 0.6666666666666666 does
> not meet the constraint requirement!

I tried used `filterKeys` method. But it is not working as expected. Need help!

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Based on the description of your issue, `filterKeys` should solve your problem. Since `scala 2.13` you should use `map.view.filterKeys` because `map.filterKeys` was deprecated. Just creating `val map = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c")` and then `map.view.filterKeys(x => x % 2 == 0).toMap` I will get a new `Map` with the keys that are only even

Comment: How is it not working? Show us your code and the result you got.

Comment: So when you say you tried to use something but "it is not working as expected", there are 4 things missing: (1) how exactly you used it, (2) what result you got (3) what you expected to get and (4) why you expected to get (3) rather than (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your output and making minimal assumptions about your types, I believe this is what you want:

```scala
val substring = "Some"

for ((k,v) <- map if k.toString().contains(substring)) println(s"key: $k, value: $v")
```